# IE11 setTimeout is taking more time to execute

Tags: javascript, css, performance, user-interface, animation

I am facing some issue in setTimeout in IE11 and works fine in modern browser.
I have heavy loaded page and in one of the UI functionality i have given setTimout of around 300ms But it takes around 3s to execute

setTimeout(()=> {\MyCode},300).

I am not posting any code but i just want to know whether giving settimeout inside requestframeanimation improve the turnaround time

requestAnimationFrame(() => {setTimeout(()=> {\MyCode},300)});

Need a sincere feedback

Comment: setTimeout is not function that execute your code after delay, it's only function that will invoke your code when browser will be ready at leat after the delay, if you have appliction that do lot of computation then it may not have time to invoke your setTimeout. You can try to use WebWoker and do some computation there.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout ensures that ur callback function provided to it is called after timeout period is elapsed...But if your function that called setTimeout is not done with its execution...callback function will not be called even if timeout period has been elapsed...I would suggest you to go through its documentation for more detail...Link is provided below

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals